# What should I consider when shopping for a private VPN?

Tags: vpn, privacy, ssl, sniffing, session-hijacking

I frequently rely on public wireless connections when I'm on the road, so to minimize the risk of session hijacking and packet sniffers I would like to start routing all of my connections through a private VPN.

Aside from price, what factors should one consider when shopping for VPN providers?

Comment: Consider setting your own up using a server/machine on your home Internet connection.  OpenVPN, Adito, and SSH tunnels are all great solutions.

Comment: Why shop?  OpenVPN is free and open source (+1 to @ultrasawblade for mentioning that and many other solutoins), and works very well as a solution in the business world as it provides excellent security, is very reliable, and highly configurable, plus it's not limited to a maximum number of users like most commercial products are (well, limited by your budget anyway -- you can usually buy additional licenses).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The six most important factors in my opinion are:

- Speed - You want to make sure they can guarantee a decent speed.
- limits - If they have either bandwidth or time limitations on the service, make sure it fits in to how/when you want to use the service.
- Location - If you ever plan on using internet streaming services, or other sites that are region restricted, make sure you pick a VPN service located in the correct country (or has an IP for that country)
- Cost - leading on from the three above, is it too cheap for what they are promising? If you are being offered 1GB uplink, no limits, in a top quality DC for 50p a month... something isn't right!
- Encryption - VPN is about tunnelling a network connection, believe it or not, not all VPNs have (good) encryption, check what the maximum level they offer.
- Contract terms - Unless it guarantees a lower rate and you really are happy, try to get a one month rolling contract, and possibly a trial first... You don't want to be locked in to a year contract on a rubbish service.

Answer (score -1):

Check trustworthy company's vpn and must see ip changing propersly. I will suggest a browser (Tor). its good experience. I already using for lapel pin base web.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).